# Why move semantics in C++ have rvalue reference in function signature

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Consider the below move assignment operator:

```
class MyClass {
private:
  ssize_t buf_size;
  void* buf_ptr;
public:
  MyClass &operator=(MyClass &&rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
      buf_size = rhs.buf_size;
      buf_ptr = rhs.buf_ptr;
      rhs.buf_ptr = nullptr;
      rhs.buf_size = -1;
    }
    return *this;
  }
}
```

What prevents us from using `&operator=(MyClass &&rhs)` instead of `&operator=(MyClass &rhs)` as the method's signature? As far as I understand, all the references to `rhs` should just work if `rhs` is a lvalue.

I can see one issue: using `&operator=(MyClass &rhs)` makes copy assignment operator and move assignment operator looks identical and there is no way for us to identify which operator to call. But are there any deeper reasons?

Comment: We have had an [`auto_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr) class that used lvalue reference for its move constructor (because rvalue references were not yet available). Turned out not to be a great idea, even if it was technically possible.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate, but the motivation and design of rvalue references has already been explained in a multitude of other Q&As.

Comment: You should be able to move from temporary, which would not be possible with lvalue reference signature. Besides moving plain object may be unexpected for most users. Using  rvalue signature forces to use std::move for moving lvalue objects. Which make the move explicit (not surprinsing) in this case.

Comment: You can also read my comment the other way around. You could implement a move semantic through using an lvalue reference but, then, you will not be able to move temporaries. You will surprise your user by possibly invalidating their copied objects. Users that are accustomed to use std::move will be surprised to see it not compiling.

Comment: I believe a single sentence from the original proposal for move semantics answers this question succinctly: ["The refusal to move from lvalues using copy syntax is key to the safety of move_ptr."](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "deeper reason" for rvalue references than to be distinct from lvalue references. Automatically determining whether a reference is to an lvalue or an rvalue, and executing the correct code in response, is the entire reason for their existence. For instance, `myClass = MyClass{}` won't work with a function taking an lvalue reference, because a temporary is not an lvalue.